# User Profile Pictures

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

SharePoint 2010 + December 2011 CU.

Got User Profiles syncing with Active Directory and configured to pull in picture from AD.

I've got a single Site Collection at the moment, and adding users to a "Person" field in a list.  Most of these users have not visited the site collection yet.  Some users are getting profile pictures to display, some are not.

I've re-run a Full user profile sync and also re-run the "User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" timer job.

UPDATE:
Found a few references that indicate a need to run "[Update-SPProfilePhotoStore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607547%28v=office.14%29.aspx)" cmdlet after you import new pictures/profiles:

- http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/18/import-user-profile-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/
- http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=253

In the documentation for the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore cmdlet, it indicates:

> After upgrading from Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 to Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010, run the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore cmdlet to ensure that the SharePoint profile photo store is compatible with SharePoint Server 2010. The Update-SPProfilePhotoStore cmdlet should be used **only after an upgrade from Office SharePoint Server 2007 has completed**.

So the question now becomes, is this truly necessary for Profile Photo sync from AD to work correctly in SharePoint 2010 in a fresh SP2010 environment (i.e. no upgrade)?  And is it necessary to run periodically as people's photos change or new users are added?

Comment: If you visit the "view user profiles" page in the user profile service app in central admin, do you see the missing pictures there?

Comment: Seems that I have to run this powershell command again after doing the import:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607547(v=office.14).aspx (eventhough the Technet article says "only run this after an upgrade from 2007".